# Java - No Duplicate number array

Tags: java, numbers, bluej

I am in the process of creating of a Lottery Program using Java via BlueJ and I am having trouble with the user inputted numbers and the number being generated by the program (up to and including 1-49), I need the numbers that are entered by the user to not be duplicate i.e. the user cannot enter 1 and 1.

I am not really sure how to get the numbers to not be duplicate i was thinking of using an Array but im not sure what type or where to begin im rather new to the whole programming thing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] LotteryNumbers = new int[6];
        int input;
        int count = 0;

        System.out.print("Welcome to my lottery program which takes\nyour lottery numbers and compares\nthem to this weeks lottery numbers!");
        System.out.print("\n\nPress the enter key to continue");
        keyIn.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < LotteryNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            count ++;

            System.out.println("Enter your five Lottery Numbers now " + count + " (must be between 1 and 49): ");
            input = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());

            if (input < 1 || input > 49)
            {
                while (input < 1 || input > 49)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number entered! \nPlease enter lottery number (between 1 and 49) " + count);
                    input = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());

                    if (input >= 1 || input <= 49)
                    {
                     LotteryNumbers[i] = input;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            LotteryNumbers[i] = input;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for your numbers.\nThe system will now check if you have any matching numbers");
        System.out.print("Press the enter key to continue");
        keyIn.nextLine();

        Random randNumGenerator = new Random();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        int[] ActLotteryNumbers = new int[6];

            for (int j = 0; j < ActLotteryNumbers.length; j++)
                {
                int roll = randNumGenerator.nextInt(49);
                ActLotteryNumbers[j] = roll;
                }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ActLotteryNumbers));

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < LotteryNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ActLotteryNumbers.length; j++)
            {
             if (LotteryNumbers[i] == ActLotteryNumbers [j])
             {
                 counter ++;
                 System.out.println("The numbers that match up are: \n" + LotteryNumbers[i]);
             }
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
          System.out.println("You had no matching numbers this week ... Try Again next week!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `Set` since it disallows duplicates?

Comment: Sorry to be a bit dumb but could you explain a bit more about what you mean?

Comment: Use a Set Class Object instead of an int Array , google for set or search the Java API to know more

Answer (score 1):

As "fge" mentioned, use Set to add all the values that you are getting from the user.

1. Get the user inputs and add it to Set.
2. Use a Iterator to check the user entered values and generated random numbers.

   ```
   Set myset = new HashSet();
   myset.add(user_input1);
   myset.add(user_input1);
   ```

To retrive use the iterator'

```
Iterator iterator = myset.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext(){
int value= iterator.next();
if(randomValue==value)
//do your logic here
}
```

Comment: Im not really sure how this works? Would I add all the possible inputs for the user i.e. numbers 1-49 in the "myset.add(user_input1);" bit? The iterator bit confuses me massively

Comment: You can add your user inputs from user scanner to the set. Once added, compare your set values with the random numbers generator.

Iterators are used to traverse the set and hasNext() returns the next element in the set

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is for a school project/lab?  (This is due to the JavaApplication8 class name)  If that is the case, what the instructor is most likely looking for is a contains method.

For a contains method you write a method that takes an integer and checks to see if it is already in your LotteryNumbers array and returns a boolean.  It would return true if it is in the array, false if it is not in it.  This method would be called before inserting the number into LotteryNumbers.  You could use your count variable that doesn't appear to be used anywhere else as the limit on your loop in the contains method to avoid checking uninitialized entries.

If there is no restriction on type, the set idea suggested by others works and is more efficient, it just depends on what you are supposed to be using for your requirements.

Additionally, the logic you use should most likely be applied to ActLotteryNumbers as well.  If you can't have duplicates incoming, you shouldn't have duplicate values in the comparing array.  Lottery isn't fair in real life, but not that unfair ;-)

First step should be checking your restrictions on this project.

Comment: The project is for college yes but the code i am using was found and I am trying to work with it because I really am not very good at this and cant really see me having anything resembling a program by the time we have to hand this in. Ive managed to get a lot done for what is being asked for apart from stopping duplicate numbers, and the money side of the program.

Comment: Break it down into small parts. And do piece by piece. The more I think about it the set won't work because it only solves duplicates, you have to maintain order as well, some sets do I believe and some don't.  If you use an ArrayList (use the api it is your friend) it has a predetermined contains method (which you should look into the mechanics of) that you can call before accepting the value.  with the code above if contains == true don't add to the ArrayList, prompt again for a number with a duplication value received message.

Comment: Hi i Have done a piece of code that will hopefully get rid of duplicates and im trying to incorporate it into the code above but im having a bit of a problem with it here is the code: 'public Set<Integer> LotteryNumbers()
    {
        Set<Integer> RandomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        RandomNumbers.add(random.nextInt(49));
        
        return RandomNumbers;'

Comment: What is the problem?  Is it the fact that you are not getting enough numbers in your set?  If that is the problem it is because the set is not adding duplicate numbers to the set (like you want).  instead of a for loop you could use a while loop with the condition RandomNumbers.size() != 6

Comment: Also, from HashSet api (api's are still your friend): Iterator() Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order.

Comment: In addition, the int passed to Random is EXCLUSIVE to the range of numbers and it INCLUDES 0 (Random api - nextInt(int n)).